# How to move the same bootstrap modal when clicking different anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I'm using bootstrap 3. I have different anchor tags and each time I click one I need to open the same modal.

Above is the image of what I am trying to achieve. If I click on any of the white dots, the modal should open just above it. The same modal should open, no matter which of the anchor tags I click. If the modal is open, the background turns black.

If I need to change the modal to something else to make this work, that is also fine.

Comment: Think you've forgot to add the image my friend

Comment: @TobyCannon heres a link in cse its not displaying     http://imgur.com/O7Hu9ZX

Comment: Could you possibly provide some code, and maybe a mockup of it in a Fiddle or Bootply?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8shwievn1ovd66j/AABejHUfe0ZDBnjl2NmiZV1sa?dl=0

Comment: added the sharable link.. tried to setup a fiddle but it was creating problems.... heres the existing one.. have to make it like the mock above